# I'm having trouble with Related Product "tax_query" 'terms' value

Tags: custom-post-types, php, metabox, get-posts, tax-query

I have two custom page types. the first is "product" and the second is "accessories". On the product page, there is the accessories category "inputs" raleted post. Inputs encode values like "0601,0603 etc". These codes are also product codes. When I enter the product code with the metabox, functions start in certain areas. such as product table, product picture. How can I print this code in the term section.

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Working code;

```
<?php $article_list     = get_post_meta         ( get_the_ID(), 'products_article_list',    true);?>

    <div class="product_container">
        <div class="product_row">
            <div class="article_section">
                <div class="section_first">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode($article_list); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="related_section">
                <div class="section_second">
                    <h3 class="heading"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_title() );?>'s Accessories</h3>
                    <?php $args = array(
                        'post_type'         =>  'accessories',
                        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                        'posts_per_page'    =>  12,
                        'tax_query'         =>  array(
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'inputs',
                                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                                    'terms'    => '0601',
                                                ),
                                            ),
                        "orderby"           =>  array(
                                                    'featured_until' => 'RAND',
                                                    'date' => 'ASC'
                                                ),  
                        'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
                    );
                    $related_items = new WP_Query( $args );
                        if ($related_items->have_posts()) :
                        while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();?>
                        <div class="related_post">
                            <div class="image"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(300,200), array('class'=>'img-responsive') );?></a></div>
                            <div class="text"><h4><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4><?php the_excerpt();?></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Not Working

```
<?php $article_list     = get_post_meta         ( get_the_ID(), 'products_article_list',    true);?>

    <div class="product_container">
        <div class="product_row">
            <div class="article_section">
                <div class="section_first">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode($article_list); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="related_section">
                <div class="section_second">
                    <h3 class="heading"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_title() );?>'s Accessories</h3>
                    <?php $args = array(
                        'post_type'         =>  'accessories',
                        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                        'posts_per_page'    =>  12,
                        'tax_query'         =>  array(
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'inputs',
                                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                                    'terms'    => $article_list,
                                                ),
                                            ),
                        "orderby"           =>  array(
                                                    'featured_until' => 'RAND',
                                                    'date' => 'ASC'
                                                ),  
                        'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
                    );
                    $related_items = new WP_Query( $args );
                        if ($related_items->have_posts()) :
                        while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();?>
                        <div class="related_post">
                            <div class="image"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(300,200), array('class'=>'img-responsive') );?></a></div>
                            <div class="text"><h4><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4><?php the_excerpt();?></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to use this query result because I use this query in many places

```
<?php $article_list     = get_post_meta         ( get_the_ID(), 'products_article_list',    true);?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is 'products_article_list' meta returned from in `$article_list`?

```
<?php $article_list = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), products_article_list', true);?>
```

Is it a list of ids eg. '0601,0603' or is it an array?

`tax_query` terms argument requires an array. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

So if it's stored as a list of ids all you need to do is [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the list and it should work.

```
   ...
   'tax_query' =>  array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' =>  'inputs',
           'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => explode(',', $article_list),
       ),
   ),
   ...
```

Comment: Tim, first of all thank you but, I tried but it didn't work.

Accessories post taxonomy values; 0601 or 0602 I run these values and the value as a related post on the products page

it works like this;  'terms'    => '0601',

I want that product page to get the code automatically. This code is also the product code

Comment: Thank you Tim, I solved it with a slight modification, using the code you provided.